# Python print a line that contains a number greater than "x" in a file

Tags: python-2.7

I'm new in Python, I have a script that prints all lines in a file that contains 9 using python:

```
    #!/usr/bin/env phyton

    import re

    testFile = open("test.txt", "r")

    for line in testFile:

        if re.findall("\\b9\\b", line):

            print line
```

Now, how can I print all lines that contains a number greater than 9?

test.txt:

number1 9

number2 10

number3 5

number4 6

number5 15

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use regular expression grouping:

```
for line in testFile:
    m = re.search(r"\b(\d+)\b", line)
    if m is not None and int(m.group(1)) >= 9:
        print line
```

The `(\d+)` extracts the text matched by that part of the regex into `m.group(1)`. Then the `int()` converts that to an integer and compares with 9.

This will extract the *first* instance of a number within each line. If you want to search all numbers in a line, you will need to use something like `re.finditer()` in combination with the above.

Comment: FYI, this works if there is only one number in the line (which from your example.txt it appears there is).

Comment: @PaulDraper: I just added another bit to my answer that addresses that.

Answer (score 0):

This prints the line if there is any space-separated number greater than 9.

```
testFile = open("test.txt", "r")

for line in testFile:
    for word in line.split():
        try:
            if int(word) > 9:
                print line
                break
        except ValueError:
            pass
```

Or, for your example

```
testFile = open("test.txt", "r")

for line in testFile:
    if int(line.split()[1]) > 9:
        print line
```